# How to run two JBoss-EAP 6.4 instances in two JRE/JDK in Linux

Tags: jboss, java-8, jboss-eap-6

I have two applications: one is JDK 1.6 compatible and another is JDK 1.8 compatible. I need to deploy these two in JBoss-EAP 6.4.

Below are the steps I followed:

**1**. I created two instances standalone and standalone1 and changed the port number in Linux `/opt/jboss/standalone/standalone-full-ha.xml` and `/opt/jboss/standalone2/standalone-full-ha.xml`

**2**. created two JAVA_HOME and JAVA_HOME1 and changed the path as

`/home/app/JDK/jdk1.6.0_26/bin:/home/app/JDK/jre1.8.0_111/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin`**

**3**. Created two services in `/etc/app1` and `/etc/app2` and in `app1` set the path as JAVA_HOME and in `app2` as JAVA_HOME

```
[ -r /etc/java/java.conf ] && . /etc/java/java.conf
export JAVA_HOME1
```

But while starting `app2` it is not pointing to JDK 1.8; it is pointing to 1.6 and both instances are not starting up. Could you help me on this?

Comment: Is there a reason to run them in two separate containers?

Comment: Though I know we can compile application in jdk1.6 and can run in jre1.8. But I am wondering if anything fails in jre1.8. So I want do deploy application in one instance which will point to jre1.6 and other one which will point to jre1.8. 

I deployed the application which is compiled in 1.6 in jboss which is pointing to jre1.8 and its running but not tested all modules.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. There is no need of two instances.If we compile the application in jdk1.6 and run in jer1.8 it works.